# How to choose the correct preposition used when referring to books' topics

Tags: preposition

In a recent Slow German Podcast the following sentence can be found:

> Es gibt zwei Bücher, die ich dir zum Thema empfehlen kann.

My question is:

What determines the use of the preposition `zu` here instead of e.g. `an`?

When these English sentences are entered into Google Translate

> I can recommend 2 books about the sport.
>
> I can show you 2 books on the sport.

it responds with these German sentences

> Ich kann 2 Bücher über den Sport empfehlen.
>
> Ich kann Ihnen 2 Bücher über den Sport zeigen.

Is Google Translate incorrect in using über instead of zu here?

Comment: *Zu+Dativ* is often used instead of *für+Akkusativ*. This is a higher register of language. The preposition *an* is completely unrelated.

Comment: As always you don't give any explanation why it should be *an*.

Comment: I translate the sentence as, There are 2 books that I can recommend to you ON the topic. The German preposition "an" is commonly translated to the English word "on" in various references and therefore I wonder why the German preposition "an" could not be used in this sentence in place of zu.

Comment: It may be "ON the topic" in english, but it is more an "TO the topic" in german. Maybe it helps to think "i recommend you books in regards TO the topic". There is no real use of "an" in this case. That would be wrong is would say.

Comment: So what I am trying to understand is, which part of the sentence is it that is determining the use of zu? Is it the verb empfehlen that requires it, or is it the noun Thema that requires it? And if it is the noun then what about the noun is it that calls for this preposition? If the noun were instead, Restaurant or mein Vater, would the same preposition be used?

Comment: It's *Thema*, mostly. The choice of topical prepositions is to avoid misunderstandings. If you said *für deinen Vater* for example, it could be understood as you being a delivery boy for the books meant **for** your father. If you used *zu deinem Vater* instead, it's clear these are books **about** some condition your father has.

Answer (score 6):

To combine the comments under your question into an answer:

> There are two books that I can recommend to you **`ON`** the topic.

can not be translated word for word, but has to be seen as

> There are two books that I can recommend to you `in regards`**`TO`** the topic.

So `an` does not appear at all.

---

Sometimes `zu` and `für` can be used interchangeably.

> Es gibt zwei Bücher, die ich dir `zum` Thema empfehlen kann.
>
> Es gibt zwei Bücher, die ich dir `für das` Thema empfehlen kann.

But this depends on what you are referencing. `Thema` in this case.

> Es gibt zwei Bücher, die ich dir `zu deinem` Vater empfehlen kann.

There are two books that I can recommend with your father as the subject.

> Es gibt zwei Bücher, die ich dir `für deinen` Vater empfehlen kann.

There are two books that I can recommend your father might enjoy.

> Es gibt zwei Bücher, die ich dir `für das` Thema empfehlen kann.

only works because the intention of this recommendation is that you will study `das Thema`.

Comment: I have not quite understood what is meant with "Es gibt Bücher für das Thema" from your explanation. What does it have to do with studying "das Thema"?